# Pattern matching for Japanese string have issues in java

Tags: java, regex, cjk

I have a strange issue while pattern matching only Japaneese characters in Java. 
Let me explain by code.

```
private static final Pattern ADDRESS_STRING_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("^[\\p{L}\\d\\s\\p{Punct}]{1,200}$");
private static boolean isValidInput(final String input, Pattern pattern) {
    return pattern.matcher(input).matches();
}
System.out.println("こんにちは、元気ですか");
```

Here I am matching any Letter,Space, digit or Punctuation letters 1 to 200.

Now this will always return false. After some debugging found that the issue is with one character "、" . If I add that character as part of the regular expression it works fine.

Anyone come across this issue ? Or is this bug in Java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that [`、` (`U+3001   IDEOGRAPHIC COMMA`) belongs to "Punctuation, other" Unicode category](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E3%80%81#title) and `\\p{Punct}` only matches ASCII punctuation by default. If you use a `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` option or `(?U)` embedded flag option, it will match (i.e. the pattern might look like `"(?U)^[\\p{L}\\d\\s\\p{Punct}]{1,200}$"`). However, this may impact `\d` and `\s`, and I am not sure you want to match all Unicode digits and whitespace.

An alternative is to use `\p{P}\p{S}` (to match Unicode punctuation and symbols) instead of `\p{Punct}` (the POSIX character class matches both punctuation and symbols).

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/3TvZr3) printing *true*:

```
private static final Pattern ADDRESS_STRING_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{L}\\d\\s\\p{P}\\p{S}]{1,200}$");
private static boolean isValidInput(final String input, Pattern pattern) {
        return pattern.matcher(input).matches();
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(isValidInput("こんにちは、元気ですか",ADDRESS_STRING_PATTERN));
}
// => true
```